# Primefaces commandLink process @this and second component

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have such code:

```
    <p:inputTextarea id="wywiad" value="#{badWizytaCrud.inst.wywiad}"/>
    <p:commandLink oncomplete="PF('wywiadListDialogJs').show()" actionListener="#{comDictionaryList.selectDictionary('Wywiad')}"
            update=":wywiadForm" rendered="#{badWizytaCrud.editable}" immediate="true" process="@this,wywiad" global="false">
            <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></div>
    </p:commandLink>
```

and my problem is the partial process doesn't work on `wywiad` component. It works when I remove `@this` from process attribute of commandLink and leave just the one component, but I need both components there. I tried different compositons in process attribute:

"wywiad,@this", "@this,wywiad", "@this wywiad".

None of them work. Is there anything I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening due to `immediate="true"` on your commandLink. If you remove `immediate="true"` on `p:commandLink` everything should work as you expected. To understand the effect of `immediate` attribute please see excellent article by BalusC here http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html

Hope this helps.